# How to lock a matrix cell in multithreading process

Tags: c, multithreading

Let's say I have 'n' number of threads. All of these threads are accessing the same matrix, and they are doing some operation.

When a thread does its job (the job is going to an adjacent location in the 2-D array), I have either lock the entire matrix, do its job, then unlock it and let other threads to do their job too. Or, I can lock their adjacent locations, in this case, 8 location including diagonals, or I can block the target cell that thread wants to move.

I have implemented the locking entire matrix with putting pthread_t_lock() and do the job, then unlock it. In this case, I have used only one mutex. It works but I don't think that I benefit the whole multi-threading support in this kind of method.

In the second method, I don't know how to implement 8 adjacent location locking or locking the target location that thread wants to go. Should I use more than one mutex, like an array of mutexes for my whole grid? i.e. if my array is 10*10, I need to use 100 mutexes and lock 8 of them and release 8 of them for each thread when a thread wants to do its job. Or should I use another method? Also, I'm not sure that locking 8 mutexes will be atomic. Maybe I can use another mutex for locking these 8 mutexes, and release this lock when 8 mutexes are locked. But again, I'm not sure that will cause a deadlock.

The programming language is C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use atomics or you can divide and conquer if you need serious performance

Answer (score -1):

If you want a lock for each entry in a 2D array, you have 2 choices:

- have a second 2D array containing the locks, so that `myLocks[x][y]` is the lock for the entry `myArray[x][y]`.
- create a structure containing a lock and a value and create a 2D array of those structures, so that `myArray[x][y].lock` is the lock for the value at `myArray[x][y].value`.

To avoid deadlocks you'll need to acquire locks in a specific order and release the locks in the reverse order. The most logical order (at least for people that use the English language) would be "left to right, top to bottom" but any order is fine.

The problem is that it's very likely that you'll spend so much time acquiring and releasing locks (and so little time doing actual work in comparison) that it'd probably be faster to just use a single thread (and avoid the cost of acquiring and releasing locks).

You'd want to find a better compromise between the benefits of more threads and the cost of acquiring/releasing locks; like only having a lock for each row of the array (so you need to use 3 locks instead of 8 or 9), or only having a having a lock for each pair of rows (so you need to use 2 locks instead of 8 or 9).

Note that the design of the locks can (and should) depend on the order you do operations, and the order you do operations can (and should) depend on the design of the locks. For example; if you do have a lock for each row of the array, then it might make sense for each thread to do an entire row of the array (e.g. so that a thread would acquire 3 locks, then do the entire row, then release 3 locks).

Also note that it may be possible to do this without any locks at all. For example, if the array is 1000 * 1000 entries and you have 10 threads, then you can split the array into ten 1000*100 sub-arrays (one sub-array per thread) and let each thread do the top half of its sub-array; then make all threads wait until all other threads have finished the top halves of their sub-array before continuing; the let each thread do the bottom half of its sub-array.